# Deployment of flutter desktop app outside Microsoft Store

Tags: windows, flutter, deployment

In the last few days I have been trying to release the windows desktop application I developed in **flutter**. My need is to release the software to a private organization in a managed manner outside the Microsoft Store. The solutions I have checked are those regarding **InnoSetup** and **msix**.

As I continued to inform myself I read about the removal of **Microsoft Store for Business** which would have been the ideal solution for my need, I was wondering at this point what alternative Microsoft had introduced for this purpose.

Does anyone have any news about this? Thanks in advance.

I initially tested the approach with Inno Setup, which resulted in the generation of an installation file that was detected as a virus because of the inserted .ico file. Next I tested the msix library which I found to be a very good solution but requires a certificate purchased from a third party vendor. At this point my search was going toward a proprietary (Microsoft) method that would also handle my signing and release aspects as Microsoft Store does for public applications.